# How does the Redux magic work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, redux

I use web components to make sites with HTML and Javascript.  I normally pass data through properties down the DOM tree.  I have used Redux a little bit and wonder how the hell it passes data to child elements using the store/subscribe?!  I wish I knew how they do it, but I am not good enough with the typescript to read through the redux source (and too lazy).  I am not looking for a redux tutorial, I just want to know the underlying principle they use to get data to child elements in terms of plain Javascript.

Comment: That might help you - https://medium.com/@fknussel/redux-3cb5aac94a66

Comment: didn't help, I read most of it but I don't know anything about react so it was a little confusing.  I just want a straightforward (short) explanation on how the "store" data gets down to components that "subscribed" to the store.  If it is not passed by properties, how does the child component "know" the store has changed?  In plain javascript terms only

Answer (score 2):

The shortest answer is that the connected React components have called `store.subscribe(listenerCallback)`, and the callbacks are run every time an action is dispatched.  In other words, it's an event emitter that the components subscribe to.

Please see my post [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) and my ReactNext talk [A Deep Dive into ReactRedux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/06/presentation-react-redux-deep-dive/) for detailed explanations.

Comment: I have never used React, so I don't know what a react component is.  I am looking for an explanation in plain Javascript.  Is a react component the same/similar to a web component?  I am interested on how it is done in javascript and how the data gets around the web components in the DOM tree.